# Upload file to folder or subfolder on Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Im trying to create a method to upload a file stream to a sharepoint so far i have this

```
        public static void SPUploadFileStream(string username, string filePath, Stream fileData)
    {
        //string siteUrl = Configuration.SPSiteURL;
        string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
        SPUser currentUser = SPUtils.GetCurrentUser(username);
        if (currentUser == null)
        {
            throw new SPGappUnknownUserException(username);
        }

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl, currentUser.UserToken))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                bool allowWebUnsafeUpdt = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
                if (!allowWebUnsafeUpdt)
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                try
                {
                    SPCreateFolder(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), username);
                    SPFile newFile = web.Files.Add(filePath, fileData, true); //true = replace
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LoggingService.LogError(ex);
                    //site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowSiteUnsefaUpdt;
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowWebUnsafeUpdt;
                    throw new ApplicationException("ERROR "+ ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but it works ok if i have a path like `"FOLDER/file.jpg"` but it doesn't when i have subfolders `"FOLDER/SUB/file.jpg"`
can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem lies inside your `SPCreateFolder` method. It should have created folders recursively. As when the you try to add new file with

```
SPFile newFile = web.Files.Add(filePath, fileData, true); //true = replace
```

the server relative path must exist. Try following method for folder creation

```
private static void SPCreateFolder(SPWeb web, string filepath)
{
    // since you pass this as Path.GetDictionary it's no longer split by '/'
    var foldersTree = filepath.Split('\\');
    foldersTree.Aggregate(web.RootFolder, GetOrCreateSPFolder);
}

private static SPFolder GetOrCreateSPFolder(SPFolder sourceFolder, string folderName)
{
    SPFolder destination;

    try
    {
        // return the existing SPFolder destination if already exists
        destination = sourceFolder.SubFolders[folderName];
    }
    catch
    {
        // Create the folder if it can't be found
        destination = sourceFolder.SubFolders.Add(folderName);
    }

    return destination;
}
```

Then you can execute this with

```
...
    SPCreateFolder(web, Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
    SPFile newFile = web.Files.Add(filePath, fileData, true); //true = replace
...
```

Let me know if that helps